# Input type number set min value but constraint the input

Tags: html

If I set up `min = 0.5` than it will only can input 0.5 , 1.5, 2.5 etc.

It cant input a integer like 1, 2, 3 etc.

I am confused. Anyone can tell me why? And how to keep minimum is 0.5 but also accept integer?

```html
<form>
    <input  type="number" min=0.5 required>
    <input type="submit">
    </form>
```

Comment: Just to be clear, are you also going to implement an input check when number is type from keyboard?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you don't provide `step`, so the default is 1. Just set `step` attribute to resolve your task

```
<input  type="number" min=0.5 step=0.5 required>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `step` instead. i.e.

```html
<form>
    <input type="number" step="0.5" min="0.5" required>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: He wants the minimum value to be 0.5. The issue is that it steps by 1 by default, so it seems like you can' put in whole values.

Comment: oh, yes. Let me modify it. Thanks